# TableView rows re-ordering unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a problem with UITableView not preserving row order when row's come back on screen.

After scrolling down/up the order is all messed up. Row with index 1 could be in row 5's position and so on. How do I keep the row positions constant?

```
internal func tableView( tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "cell" ) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell" )

        // Set the cell's label
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Cell: \(indexPath.row)"
    }

    // Return the cell
    return cell!
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you are updating the text only when you create a new row... that is highly incorrect, because after a point the cell will be reused and it appears in its last state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only setting text when you are creating cell (when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns `nil`). You should set/change the text each time you  create or reuse the cell:

```
internal func tableView( tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "cell" ) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell" )
    }

    // Set the cell's label
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Cell: \(indexPath.row)"

    // Return the cell
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: This was a simplified example, i'm actually inserting UILabels into the cells, but this is most certainly the solution, and of course is blatantly obvious :D Thanks!